# What is the equivalent of 'tree.value' of a DecisionTree from sklearn in Spark ML?

Tags: scikit-learn, pyspark, decision-tree, apache-spark-ml

Comparing the `DecisionTree` models from Scikit-learn and Spark ML. The following very closely match each other. The one I can't map is the `value`

Schema for Spark ML `DecisionTree` data:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- prediction: double (nullable = true)
 |-- impurity: double (nullable = true)
 |-- impurityStats: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- gain: double (nullable = true)
 |-- leftChild: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- rightChild: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- split: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- featureIndex: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- leftCategoriesOrThreshold: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- numCategories: integer (nullable = true)

sklearn tree.feature        --> sparkML root.split.featureIndex
sklearn tree.threshold      --> sparkML.root.leftCategoriesOrThreshold
sklearn tree.children_left  --> sparkML root.leftChild
sklearn tree.children_right --> sparkML root.rightChild
sklearn tree.value          --> sparkML root.?
```

Comment: Could it be tree.prediction?